# elastic transcode is not writing metadata in s3, AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am using lambda function to transcode the video file I upload. Here is the code I am using in the `lambda` function.

```
var params = {
        PipelineId: pipelineId,
        Input: {
            Key: inputKey
        },
        Outputs: [{
            Key: outputKey,
            PresetId: transcoderPresetID,

        }],
        UserMetadata : {jid : 'test', vid: v001 }

    }
```

but when I check the metadata on the s3 object that was written by `elastic transcoder`, all I can see is `"content-type": "video/mp4"`

My log files are not showing any errors, am I missing something. Please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `UserMetadata` is not used when saving an object to S3.  The `UserMetadata` is sent as part of the job status notification as documented here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/notifications.html

If you wish to add custom metadata on the S3 object after transcoding, you could perform an object copy.  For example:

```php
                $s3Client->copyObject(
                    $sourceObject,
                    $sourceObject,
                    array(
                        "jid" => "test",
                        "vid" => "v001",
                        )
                );
```